# How to partition the operating system with a small disk

Tags: mount, partition, storage, database, partition-table

I would like to know what partitioning scheme in RHEL7 is more recommended to configure on a server with little disk space where an Oracle 18c database will be installed.
On the RedHat site they recommend a scheme similar to this:

/ -> 15 GB

/ boot -> 250 MB

/ home-> 8 GB

/ tmp -> 4 GB

/ u01 -> 50 GB

/ usr -> 5 GB

/ var -> 8 GB

My doubt is that the server only has 2 local 25GB SSDs (after raid 1 there is less, around 23). I have a SAN available with enough capacity for the deployment of the database but I would like to know how it is more advisable to partition the operating system on those disks independently of the fact that later I can enlarge the mount points with capacity presented from the SAN, Oracle recommends a swap 16GB (the ram has a capacity of 64GB). Please I am a little new to this and would appreciate any recommendation.
Thank you very much in advance for your responses.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/ch-swapspace#tb-recommended-system-swap-space and https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/appe-disk-partitions-overview are good to read

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need for all those partitions. `/boot` was needed when PC hardware could only boot from a small partition near the start of the disk. Some of the others you may choose to put on different types of storage (HDD, SDD, raid, no-raid).

I have `/` and `/home`. I keep these separate, so that I can more easily upgrade/change the OS. If it is a server, where you won't be using `/home`. Then you don't need that ether.

However keeping OS and data separate is a good idea, but there is more than one way to do it.

Comment: /home is not required, either; all can go in root